# How to securely permission SSH keys on my mac so they require sudo access to both use and copy

Tags: linux, ssh, security, permissions, ssh-keys

I would like to set the permissions/owner settings for the SSH keys so they require sudo access to both *use* and *copy*. This would just be an additional security step if someone were to steal my laptop while I was logged in.

I tried changing the ownership to root:

```
sudo chown root ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

but then where would I put the SSH *config* file?

Is this the correct approach, how does everyone else secure their SSH keys?

Comment: It's common practice to set the ownership to the user who the certificate will be assigned. You shouldn't have to move the OpenSSH configuration file. So common practice already would require sudo permissions to even read the file.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'd like to force the user to use `sudo` when using SSH, just as an additional precaution - i.e. the user is logged into their laptop, which is stolen. On a mac, `sudo` just requires touch-id, so it's simple. I'm just not setting it up correctly :(

Comment: What you describe is what you have asked in your question. Making sudo required to launch OpenSSH is entirely different then setting the correct permissions on the keys on the client. I think you are trying to protect against a threat vector that isn't realistic.

Comment: Why use sudo rather just set up the ssh keys with a [passphrase](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/passphrase)?

Comment: it's mainly for my macbook pro - i can use touch-id to as a proxy for `sudo`

Comment: Lock your screen, require a passphrase for the ssh-keys.

Comment: Didn't think it was a difficult question, but if you don't know the answer, then it's all good...

Comment: You will lower your security by running `ssh` as root, as a compromise of your session (an exploit in OpenSSH client) will pwn your system, not just your user. Unrealistic, but still - don't use `sudo` unless required. Use a passphrase.

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in the comments, this is not the right approach.

Instead, you should be using a passphrase for your private key (which I'm sure can be set up with your fingerprint aswell).

Alternatively, you could try looking into server-side `pam` modules that directly support "touch-id" instead of a passkey (didn't look it up).

However, if you *really* want this to work:

```
sudo --preserve-env=HOME ssh [...]
```